# F3: Rerouting to a dynamic URL

Tags: dynamic, parameters, fat-free-framework, reroute

I am having some difficulties rerouting to a dynamic URL from within my controller.

in routes.ini

```
GET /admin/profiles/patient/@patientId/insert-report = Admin->createReport
```

in the controller Admin.php, in method createReport():

```
$patientId = $f3->get('PARAMS.patientId');
```

My attempt (in Admin.php):

```
$f3->reroute('admin/profiles/patient/' . echo (string)$patientId . '/insert-report');
```

Question: How to reroute to the same URL (where some error messages will be displayed) without
changing completely the routing, that is attaching patientId as a URL query parameter ?

Thanks, K.

Answer (score 2):

The `echo` statement is not needed to concatenate strings:

```
$f3->reroute('admin/profiles/patient/' . $patientId . '/insert-report');
```

Here are 3 other ways to get the same result:

**1) build the URL from the current pattern**

(useful for rerouting to the same route with a different parameter)

```
// controller
$url=$f3->build($f3->PATTERN,['patientId'=>$patientId]);
$f3->reroute($url);
```

**2) reroute to the same pattern, same parameters**

(useful for rerouting from POST/PUT/DELETE to GET of the same URL)

```
// controller
$f3->reroute();
```

**3) build the URL from a named route**

(useful for rerouting to a different route)

```
;config file
GET @create_report: /admin/profiles/patient/@patientId/insert-report = Admin->createReport
```

```
// controller
$url=$f3->alias('create_report',['patientId'=>$patientId']);
$f3->reroute($url);
```

or shorthand syntax:

```
// controller
$f3->reroute(['create_report',['patientId'=>$patientId']]);
```